# Auto update Windows C++ application from non privileged (standard) user account

Tags: windows, auto-update

I am having a main application in C++ which will be installed in Program Files folder and under UAC control i.e. non-privileged user cannot write or change the data inside the main application folder.

I also have an auto update C++ application which will be used to auto update the main application without standard user intervention.

With standard user being the regular user of the application and system being far away from physical access from Administrator, I would like to know the ways through which I can auto update my application with standard user logged in the system.

One approach I am aware of is create and install a service from Admin account which can update the application from standard user account.

Is there any other way/tools which can help me in this if I don't want to use creating service as an option for auto updating my application?

Comment: Depending on the exact use case - if the user is technically admin and you just want your auto-updater to run without UAC prompt, you can create a scheduled task with the "use highest privileges" flag set. (Creating the task will require elevated privileges, but there no UAC confirmation required when the task is run.)

Comment: As long as the installer has admin access, you can create an update task that runs as SYSTEM in the services session. I don't think you want it to require running as the user of an interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your application, and you are producing the installer, you can implement so called "user install", i.e. application is installed not to `C:\Program Files`, but to `C:\Users\<user folder>\AppData\Local\<Application Folder>`. Drawback: application will be available for that specific user, another user should install application for himself separately, but you will be able to update it w/o need for admin privileges. Maybe you also need to check that your application can work if it is installed in a some other location than "Program Files". That's it.

Comment: Requirement is that standard user should not be able to write/change contents in the application folder, only update application can change the contents of application folder.
That's why I am installing it in Program Files.

Installing in C:\Users\<user folder>\AppData\Local\<Application Folder> will give full user permission to update contents of the folder.

Comment: Then you only can schedule a task which runs under account with admin privileges and updates application.